# When using automation tests to drive the design of your automation framework, what is this called?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, ui-automation, atdd

We use a very effective technique of developing automated functional tests for our system. We write the functional tests first(like a Selenium test), based on the manual test case, and then use those tests to drive the development of our **automation framework**, not the System Under Test.

Would this style of development still be classified as TDD? I've only seen TDD in terms of unit tests. And in that instance, we use unit tests as the requirements to drive the development of the final system under test. So I feel that it's a bit different than what I mentioned above.

This is also a bit different from Acceptance Test Driven Development because the whole team is not meeting to discuss an acceptance test that will be used to validate the system later. Rather, an Automation Engineer simply uses the steps of a manual test case to drive the design of the automation system. Not the System Under Test.

This almost feels like a Functional Test Driven Automation, or something like that. However, I have not seen such a term used anywhere. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

How big a team are you on? Am I right to say this is what you do: You are given a manual test case, and then you convert it into an automated test case. Is that correct?

That sounds like re-factoring, or just automating an aspect of quality control. TDD is a *development technique*, not a testing technique, despite the name. In other words, TDD is focused on **MAKING SOMETHING NEW**, not making sure something works (that is testing). Where do you're manual test cases come from? That person who gives these test to you might be doing TDD.